# How to check if string only has tabs (\t char) in it

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to verify a set of strings and I'm in the need to know which ones are solely tabs.

Ex:

```
$t="\t\t\t\t";
$t="\t";
```

I've tried preg_match command but I do not seem to do the proper regex, tried with trim but it deletes the \n chars

Code I've tried:

```
if(preg_match('~\s*~', $string) ) {
       //do something...
  }
```

Comment: `if(preg_match('~^\t+$~', $string) ) {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex is generally less efficient for simple tasks like this. You can instead use the `trim` function to remove all tabs from the string and test that the remainder is empty:

```
if ($t && !trim($t, "\t")) {
    //do something...
}
```